# C# store int in byte array

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, byte

I work on a small project and i need to store 4 `int` types  in a byte array(which will be sent later on a socket).

This is the code:

```
       int a = 566;          
       int b = 1106;
       int c = 649;
       int d = 299;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16];

        bytes[0] = (byte)(a >> 24);
        bytes[1] = (byte)(a >> 16);
        bytes[2] = (byte)(a >> 8);
        bytes[3] = (byte)a;
```

I shifted the bits of the first value,but i'm not sure now how to retrieve it back...doing the reversed process.

I hope my question is clear,if i missed somthing i'll be glad to explain it again.
Thanks.

Comment: Use `BitConverter.GetBytes(...)` and other direction use `BitConverter.ToInt32(...)`

Comment: @x... but i need to insert 4 bytes into this array.sorry i've edited my question.`BitConvertor` return a new byte array,i dont want to make it more complicated and to merge the both 4 byte[] array i'll get from the `BitConvertor.`

Comment: You mean this? `int b = bytes[0] << 24 | bytes[1] << 16 | bytes[2] << 8 | bytes[3]`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen awesome.you should write it as answer :0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract the `Int32` back out from the byte array, use this expression:

```
int b = bytes[0] << 24
      | bytes[1] << 16
      | bytes[2] << 8
      | bytes[3]; // << 0
```

Here is a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lP9eXf) that demonstrates.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on you comment reply, you can do it like this:

```
int a = 10;
byte[] aByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);

int b = 20;
byte[] bByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);

List<byte> listOfBytes = new List<byte>(aByte);
listOfBytes.AddRange(bByte);

byte[] newByte = listOfBytes.ToArray();
```

Comment: that's exactly what i didn't want to do. There isn't a solution with simple bit manipulation or somthing? @x...i'm also looking for..efficiency..it's for a real time program..i would really like to use the low level stuff.

Comment: So, you want to do it in C/C++ way with bit shifting ?

Comment: bit shifting isn't only related to c/c++.. haha

Comment: You can take a look in .NET source code : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,1618fc20415532f2

Comment: @Slashy - Do you really have a performance issue doing this? This is an extremely quick computation.

Comment: @Enigmativity not really,but i also prefered to work with the bits myself :)

Comment: @Slashy - Then make your life easy and use the `BitConverter`.

Comment: It's like : There is a rocket to the moon, and @Slashy want to learn how to ride a bicycle first...:=)

Comment: @x... funny.but real.

Comment: @x... - It's more like there's an iPhone, but Slashy wants to get a soldering iron and some transistors and build his own.

Comment: The rocket analogy isn't bad, b/c it might be overkill to use a rocket to drive to the next store, instead of using your bike. Besides bit-shifting isn't that complicated anyway. Also `BitConverter` might get you into endianness trouble, when exchanging data between different systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MemoryStream` to wrap an array of bytes, and then use `BinaryWriter` to write items to the array, and `BinaryReader` to read items from the array.

Sample code:

```
int a = 566;
int b = 1106;
int c = 649;
int d = 299;

// Writing.

byte[] data = new byte[sizeof(int) * 4];

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(a);
    writer.Write(b);
    writer.Write(c);
    writer.Write(d);
}

// Reading.

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    a = reader.ReadInt32();
    b = reader.ReadInt32();
    c = reader.ReadInt32();
    d = reader.ReadInt32();
}

// Check results.

Trace.Assert(a == 566);
Trace.Assert(b == 1106);
Trace.Assert(c == 649);
Trace.Assert(d == 299);
```