# what the purpose of Right and left shift

Tags: c#

i know what left shift and right shift do

when i have  0011 >> 1 with right shift its would be   →  0001

its just divide the value on `2` if we use 0011 >> 2 its will divide on 4 etc...
but what the purpose
i just start working with tcp socket and i see we sent the size of the buffer like this

```
   var bytes = new Array(4)
   bytes[1] = int >> 24
   bytes[2] = int >> 16
   bytes[3] = int >> 8
   bytes[4] = int
```

i dont know why we used 24 and 16 and 8

some time they use only `8` like

```
var bytes = new Array(2) 
   bytes[1] = int >> 8
   bytes[2] = int
```

and again when they want to read size they just use opposite of `right shift` using `left shift`

```
size = buff[1] << 24 | buff[2] << 16 | buff[3] << 8 | buff[4]
```

what the purpose of using right shift before send value and when receive it using left shift why not send its direct ?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180076/c-sharp-store-int-in-byte-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it makes life easier if you visualize working with the bits

An `int` is 4 bytes big in memory, so to have that as four individual `byte`s we can shift it around

```
some int: 11111111 10101010 11110000 11001100
```

To get these blocks of bits and 4 individual bytes we could sure divide by powers of 2, but it's harder to visualize than just sliding the whole thing to the right 24 places leaving `11111111` that we store in a byte (everything that slides off the right hand side is lost).. or sliding to the right 16 places leaving `11111111 10101010` that then cuts the `11111111` off when we store it in a byte (everything to the left of the rightmost 8 bits is lost when assigning to a byte)

It's somewhat like playing [Stacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacker_(game)) with bits

As to why you might use left shift to recompose an int from 4 bytes - imagine playing a reverse version of stacker where you have 32 slots arranged into 4 groups and you have to put *these* 8 bits (from the leading byte) into the leftmost bucket, then the bits of the subsequent bytes into the next bucket:

```
some byte:                            11111111
next byte:                            10101010

some int:  ________ ________ ________ ________
```

The "some byte" is going to need to be slid left 24 places, the next byte 16 places. They acquire 0s (become ints with only some bits set) as a result:

```
some byte shifted: 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000
next byte shifted:          10101010 00000000 00000000

some int result:   ________ ________ ________ ________
```

These are then bitwise ORred together to produce the result:

```
some byte: 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000
next byte: 00000000 10101010 00000000 00000000

some int:  11111111 10101010 00000000 00000000
```

OR is "work column by column, if any value in the column is a 1, the resulting value in the column is 1, otherwise it is 0"

---

> Why are these things always done as bytes?

Because that's how network transmission is, because everything, ultimately is a byte (an int is 4 bytes), or bits if you want to look at it that way. Even if you use some abstraction that writes an int to a socket, it'll convert it to bytes. Here you're just gaining an appreciation for how that conversion works out (and it doesn't have to be this way; there are other ways of arranging bits and bytes. So long as you're consistent it doesn't matter how you do it)

---

You also see it used for things like flags enums:

```
flags enum Perms{
  None = 0,
  Read = 1 << 0,
  Write = 1 << 1,
  Delete = 1 << 2
}
```

Which could also be done by

```
flags enum Perms{
  None = 0,
  Read = 2^0,
  Write = 2^1,
  Delete = 2^2
}
```

No-one will fire you for the bitshift version, though as operations they're less commonly encountered than powers so the next person that maintains the code might have to look up what it means whereas the power form is probably already well understood

As to how they came to be, bitshifting operations are/were also typically a lot faster than multiply/divide operations (they're very simple for a CPU to implement but have limited application) so were very useful for limited contexts